# jQuery change/remove underline on navigation link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that changes the border underneath the links depending on which one clicked but how do I remove it off the old link once the new link has been clicked?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.nav-link').click(function() {
      $(this).addClass("active-link");
  });
  
});
```

```css
nav {
    height: 3em;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

.nav-link {
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

.active-link {
    border-bottom: 0.2em solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav>
    <ul class="list-inline">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link active-link">Link One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link Three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link Four</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link Five</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Add `$('.nav-link').removeClass('active-link')` before click

Comment: You have found the `addClass()` method, you should have been able to find the `removeClass()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the class from the rest of them ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var links = $('.nav-link');

  links.click(function() {
      links.not(this).removeClass("active-link");
      $(this).addClass("active-link");
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm very new to jQuery I did not see the .not function

Answer (score 1):

use .removeClass()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-link').click(function() {
      $('.nav-link').removeClass("active-link");
      $(this).addClass("active-link");
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for

```
$(document).ready(function() {

      $('.nav-link').click(function() {
          $('.nav-link').removeClass("active-link");
          $(this).addClass("active-link");

      });

    });
```

Comment: I couldnt even edit it after first post and i got 3 downvote in a sec what a hypocrite society